# System.UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown from console app started from w3wp when AnonymousPipeServerStream used

Tags: c#, w3wp

I have console application that I start as process from w3wp. App should manipulate with files under website folder. Everything was working fine until I decided to communicate with console app with use of AnonymousPipeServerStream(I want to receive message from console app).

```
        var pipeServer = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.In);
        var pipeStreamReader = new StreamReader(pipeServer);

        ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);
        si.Arguments = $"{pipeServer.GetClientHandleAsString()} {arguments}";
        si.CreateNoWindow = true;
        si.UseShellExecute = false;
        si.RedirectStandardError = true;
        si.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

After this code was added console app started crashing with exception

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\... is denied.

Code that throws exception:

```
File.Open(this.Path, FileMode.CreateNew);
```

If I comment out code with AnonymousPipeServerStream everything works as expected.

Is it possible that AnonymousPipeServerStream changes principal that console app starts with or any ideas what can cause such behavior?

Comment: which instruction is throwing that exception (call stack)?

Comment: I try to create file there with File.Open(this.Path, FileMode.CreateNew);

Answer (score 0):

This appeared to be error in code not connected pipes. Sorry for the noise